# Not found build.gradle project at Project manager-Android Studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Someone knows , why at some my project I can not see `build.gradle project`at Android Studio 3? there are just build.gradle module ?

[image]

I do rebuild my project but I still do not see `build.gradle project`?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Project structure from `Android` to `Project`.
[image]

And you can find the build.gradle for project.

Comment: In that you can find your build.gradle for your project.